# Centos Atomic 7 cloud-init static network configuration NO DEFAULT GATEWAY

Tags: networking, centos7, cloud-init

I downloaded CentOS Atomic Host from [here](http://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/atomic/images/CentOS-Atomic-Host-7-Installer.iso) and installed in VirtualBox VM with Bridged adapter as the network adapter. Default installation and I only setup root password and nothing else. Then I logged in the VM and ran the command `systemctl enable cloud-init` to initialize my instance and `reboot`.
The user-data and meta-data files of cloud-init are as follows:

```
#meta-data                     |   #user-data
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
instance-id: magicatomic       |   #cloud-config
local-hostname: ss.magicatomic |   groups:
network-interfaces: |          |     - docker: [root]
  auto enp0s3                  |    write_files:
  iface enp0s3 inet static     |     - content: |
    address 192.168.1.110      |        {
    network 192.168.1.0        |           "debug": true,
    netmask 255.255.255.0      |           "hosts": ["tcp://192.168.1.110:2375"]
    broadcast 192.168.1.255    |        }
    gateway 192.168.1.1        |       path: /etc/docker/daemon.json
                               |       runcmd:
                               |         - sudo systemctl daemon-reload
                               |         - sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

But the configuration is half broken, meaning: 
Default Gateway is not set and Protocol is not set to static in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`
When I do `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`
I get

```
BOOTPROTO=none
DEVICE=enp0s3
IPADDR=192.168.1.110
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=ethernet
USERCTL=no
```

And when I do `route -n`

```
Kernel IP Routing Table
Destination   Gateway       Genmask        Flags  Metric  Ref  Use  Iface
172.17.0.0    0.0.0.0       255.255.0.0    U      0       0    0    docker0
192.168.1.0   0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0  U      100     0    0    enp0s3
```

QUESTION: No Default Gateway is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's only 25% broken...  Your cloud-init configuration results in "BOOTPROTO=none", which is equivalent with "BOOTPROTO=static"  More info at these links.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/41630
or
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167083/bootproto-none-static-dhcp-and-etc-resolv-conf

I'm still looking for why the default gateway is not set.  Have you tried removing that line?  I'm reviewing the docs...  http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config-format-v1.html

Update:  This appears to be a known issue, and is being actively worked on.  The bugs tracking this issue are https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1492726 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1686856

As a workaround, I would suggest adding a line to runcmd with something like this `nmcli con modify enp0s3 ipv4.gateway 192.168.1.1`

Comment: Unfortunately, the workaround you suggested doesn't seem to work.

Also, approximately how much time does it take to resolve such bugs because I need to use this in production so need to decide what should be done.

Comment: I don't think I can estimate how much time a resolution would take.  All of the code changes have been completed.  It appears to be a packing / delivery delay at this point.  My workaround may have gotten NetworkManager's profile name wrong.  It might be "System enp0s3"...  If you have a booted instance, you can verify the name with the command "nmcli connection show"

Comment: i had the same problem; i ended up doing a write_files in cloud-config's userdata, which wrote: GATEWAY=192.168.0.1 into /etc/sysconfig/network and a run-cmd: systemctl restart network - that's ugly but it works.